# penetration of rolled homogeneous steel, issues with finding the joules required to punch through

Tags: materials

So I am making a tech demo demonstrating fairly realistic penetration physics. I Have run into some confusion due to my lack of knowledge. If I have the resistance of the armor in MPa, that means I have the amount of joules acting in a square meter, so i divide by the area of the cross section of the shell, in meters (assuming it's a cylinder) then multiply by the thickness of the armor, also in meters, to get the required joules to punch through the armor of the given thickness with a round of the given cross sectional area?

Comment: Pascals is a measure of pressure/stress not energy which is measured in joules. The wording of your second sentence needs to be changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MPa is pressure, giving you measures of $\frac{N}{m ^2} \times 10^9$.

Multiplying it by cross section ($m^2$) gives you Force, measured in Newtons.

If you multiply that by thickness, the value you get will be in Joules ($N \times m$).

So great, the units seem to work.

The problem is finding the values you should use.  I'm assuming you found the ultimate tensile stress or some similar property for the material and took that for the MPa value.

You cannot just multiply it by the volume removed to get required energy, even though the units work.  Consider the situation.  The cross sectional area shouldn't directly matter.  Regardless of the area, you are only really punching through the perimeter over a specific thickness, not an area through a thickness (you can keep the centre of what you punch intact).

In reality the equations are much more involved than the ultimate material strength and the amount of material removed.  It includes factors like the area vs. perimeter relationship and would also require information on what you are using for a punch.

Comment: good answer and the link here gives more info : http://www.image2punch.com/Calculation-for-Punching-Force

Comment: It didn't even occur to me that I was describing vaporizing the armor XD, thanks for catching that. Thankfully this is just a hobby project and it doesn't have to be 100% realistic. I will probably end up fudging the numbers a bit, try tuning it to real world gun penetration values and getting a good feeling mechanic rather that an 100% accurate mechanic, since at the end of the day i'm making a game not a sim lol

Answer (score 0):

A value in MPa is likely to be a yield stress or ultimate tensile stress. This is fine for static forces and conditions where strain rates are low eg if you are punching a hole in a plate with a hydraulic press.

However in the context of armour we re often looking at very high strain rates and in this case material properties for static conditions may not apply. For example with kinetic energy penetrators you can see viscous flow as well as shockwave induced effects like spalling.

So realistic models tend to be complex, based on empirical data and highly contextual.

What might be better is too look at empirical standard for armour plating eg [this graphic for Armox](http://www.ssab.co.uk/products/brands/armox/recommended-plate-thickness-for-different-protection-levels) Obviously a lot of the fine detail of this sort of data is proprietary but you should at least be able to get order of magnitude figures.